# Not Getting Desired Result in Python Random Number Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to `Python` and I am doing a "Lottery Game."

I should note I am using `Python 3.4.2` and the `Python GUI`.

The program is a Lottery Game in which it:

- Generates two random numbers, each between 0 and 9
- Allow the user to guess two numbers (between 0 and 9)
- Prompts the user with an appropriate message for entering input
- Compares each of the user’s guesses to the two random numbers and display a message that includes the user’s guess as a 2 digit number

For the game, depending on what you guess, you win based on these conditions:

- Any one matching ----> $1000
- Two matching, not in order ----> $10,000
- Two matching in exact order ----> $100,000
- No matches ----> $0

I would, for example, guess 4 5 and the random numbers generated would be 6 4 but I would get $0 or "No Matches."

I think the error lies in being unable to get the "Any one matching" correct, or this snippet of code:

```
elif guess1 == number1 | guess1 == number2 | guess2 == number1 | guess2 == number2:
    number1 = str(number1)
    number2 = str(number2)
    guess1 = str(guess1)
    guess2 = str(guess2)
    print('Your guess was ' + guess1 + guess2)
    print('The lottery number is ' + number1 + number2)
    print('Congrats, you win 1,000')
```

Here is my code I wrote:

```
import random

number1 = random.randint(0, 9)
number2 = random.randint(0, 9)

print('Welcome to the Lottery Game! You must guess two numbers.')

print('Guess a number from 0 - 9')
guess1 = input()
guess1 = int(guess1)

print('Guess a number from 0 - 9')
guess2 = input()
guess2 = int(guess2)

if guess1 == number1 & guess2 == number2:
    number1 = str(number1)
    number2 = str(number2)
    guess1 = str(guess1)
    guess2 = str(guess2)
    print('Your guess was ' + guess1 + guess2)
    print('The lottery number is ' + number1 + number2)
    print('Congrats, you win 100,000')
elif guess1 == number2 & guess2 == number1:
    number1 = str(number1)
    number2 = str(number2)
    guess1 = str(guess1)
    guess2 = str(guess2)
    print('Your guess was ' + guess1 + guess2)
    print('The lottery number is ' + number1 + number2)
    print('Congrats, you win 10,000')
elif guess1 == number1 | guess1 == number2 | guess2 == number1 | guess2 == number2:
    number1 = str(number1)
    number2 = str(number2)
    guess1 = str(guess1)
    guess2 = str(guess2)
    print('Your guess was ' + guess1 + guess2)
    print('The lottery number is ' + number1 + number2)
    print('Congrats, you win 1,000')
else:
    number1 = str(number1)
    number2 = str(number2)
    guess1 = str(guess1)
    guess2 = str(guess2)
    print('Your guess was ' + guess1 + guess2)
    print('The lottery number is ' + number1 + number2)
    print('Sorry, you win nothing.')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To summarize the linked question: use `and` and `or` for boolean logic, not `&` and `|`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Switched "&" and "|" with "and" and "or" and it worked. Thanks!!! :)